# Sitemap generator in text on Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sitemap

I have some site, for example `http://example.com`
I want to generate a sitemap as a list of URIs, such as:

- `http://example.com/main`
- `http://example.com/tags`
- `http://example.com/tags/foo`
- `http://example.com/tags/bar`

I have found a good application for it: [iGooMap](http://www.pointworks.de/software/igoomap/index.php)
iGooMap can generate the needed URI list as a text file (not an XML File).
Here is a visual representation of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Here is what I would like to have]

I want to have this type of a sitemap generated in Ruby (*not* Rails).
I have found [SiteMapGenerator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator), but it only generates an .XML file, however as stated  I need a text file.

Is there a solution for Ruby to create a list of links for a given site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is not a *sitemap generator* in Ruby, but a *web spider* in Ruby. I recommend [Anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/)

```
require 'anemone'

links = []

Anemone.crawl("http://www.foo.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
      links << page.url
  end
end

File.open('./link_list.txt', 'wb'){|f| f.write links.join("\n") }
```

This yields a file called `link_list.txt` with the following contents:

```
http://www.foo.com/
http://www.foo.com/digimedia_privacy_policy.html
```

There's also [Wombat](https://github.com/felipecsl/wombat), [Spidr](http://spidr.rubyforge.org/), [Pioneer](https://github.com/fl00r/pioneer) and many more.

---

**Edit:** As suggested by @ChrisCummings, it might be a better idea to use a `Set` instead of an `Array` in order to prevent duplicates. I also recommend sorting the links alphabetically which will make the output file more easily readable for humans:

```
require 'anemone'
require 'set'

links = Set.new                                    # Set will prevent duplicates

Anemone.crawl("http://www.foo.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
    links << page.url.to_s                         # to_s needed in order to sort
  end
end

File.open('./link_list.txt', 'wb') do |f|
  f.write links.sort.join("\n")                    # call to sort added
end
```

Comment: Two cups of tea this gentleman!
This is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I would use a Set instead of an Array as my collection class to avoid duplicate URLs. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Answer (score 4):

You can extend `sitemap_generator` with custom adapters, for example:

```
require 'sitemap_generator'
require 'nokogiri'

module SitemapGenerator
  class TextFileAdapter
    def write(location, raw_data)
      # Ensure that the directory exists
      dir = location.directory
      if !File.exists?(dir)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
      elsif !File.directory?(dir)
        raise SitemapError.new("#{dir} should be a directory!")
      end

      doc = Nokogiri::XML( raw_data )
      txt = doc.css('url loc').map(&:text).join("\n")

      open(location.path, 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(txt)
      end
    end
  end
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = 'http://example.com'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create(
  :adapter => SitemapGenerator::TextFileAdapter.new,
  :sitemaps_namer => SitemapGenerator::SitemapNamer.new(:sitemap, :extension => '.txt')
) do
  add '/home', :changefreq => 'daily', :priority => 0.9
  add '/contact_us', :changefreq => 'weekly'
end
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines
```

This results in a file `public/sitemap1.txt`:

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/home
http://example.com/contact_us
```

Comment: Thnx, but I need add all uri in "add '/%urn%', :changefreq => 'weekly'" template?
I need automatic generate all uri from site in text file.

Comment: Example: Site have two page. /foo, /bar.  
/foo page have linke to /bar page.  
<!-- file /foo.html -->  
<a href="/bar">Bar</a>  
  
I need sitemap.txt with next source:  
http://example.com/foo/  
http://example.com/bar/  
  
This case also called "spider".

Comment: see my second answer, please.